# Windows 7 laptop with problems shutting down

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, shutdown, thinkpad

This is a thinkpad convertible tablet with Windows 7. When you try to shut down, it seizes at a screen with a gradient background and a Think/Thinkpad logo (forgot which). If you close it at that point, wait for the moon led to light up (meaning it's sleeping), then open it back up, it immediately continues and shuts down successfully.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

That is because it is configured to sleep when the lid is closed